# nginx error : worker_connections are not enough

Tags: nginx

I'm a new to Nginx.

What i want to do with Nginx is Traffic load balancing.
To do it, i configured nginx.conf like below

## system structure

```
      udp        udp
    A <--> Nginx <--> Backend 1
                 <--> Backend 2
```

## nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

stream {
upstream udp_upstreams {
   server 1:1:1:1:9997 fail_timeout=60s;
   server 1:1:1:2:9997 fail_timeout=60s;
}

server {
    listen 9000 udp;
    proxy_pass udp_upstreams;
    proxy_timeout 3s;
    proxy_responses 1;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/udp.log;
}
}

events {
    worker_connections  10240;
}
```

when i run nginx, nginx prints a lot of below message.

```
2016/04/27 04:50:36 [alert] 3137#3137: *446352 10240 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, udp client: 3.3.3.3, server: 0.0.0.0:9000, upstream: "1.1.1.2:9997", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
2016/04/27 04:50:36 [alert] 3136#3136: *446353 10240 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, udp client: 3.3.3.3, server: 0.0.0.0:9000, upstream: "1.1.1.1:9997", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
```

How do i configure nginx.conf to solve it?
I have already set the work_connections value to 40000. But it was useless.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 11):

I just ran into the same problem and found a solution after I stopped wild googling and started to read the nginx documentation. ^_^;

The parameter 'proxy_responses' tells nginx to wait for x responses to the request. I my case, log forwarding, there is non. So nginx waits for  and failes the server.

Solution:

```
proxy_responses 0
```

Docs:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_responses

Comment: Great answer! Can you also provide a link to the docs for further generations?

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. I hate answers that just throw code at you with no explanation.